# Drupal Linking changing menu paths based on page parameter

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a number of views that accept node Ids as arguments and have registered page paths, e.g. `someview/%nodeId`, `anotherview/%nodeId`, etc.  I want to have a menu which displays on the node page that links to these views for the current node.  So `node/123` should have a menu that links to `someview/123`, `anotherview/123`, and so on.

I could make a block that will do this, but I'd rather have it use the existing menu system so it fits into the existing theme styling.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you need to create a menu with dynamic parameter/argument "nodeId" added to paths of menu items.

There are (at least) two ways to do it:

### Create a menu with dynamic parameter

This module should be helpful for you: [Menu token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token)

When you have this dynamic menu created, you can just put it into a block that will be activated on the particular content type pages (this could be set in block settings).

### Create a view that will generate a menu

Another way is to create a view with nodeId as agument and style it to fit to existing menu system.

Maybe would be helpful: [Menu Node Views](http://drupal.org/project/menu_node_views)